# Is it appropriate to ask for certain software/utility?

Tags: discussion, support

Someone is looking for a specific software that complements his/her developing process. For example for producing signed XML, someone wants to compare the result of the developing code with the result of a desktop application that produces the desired result.

Is it appropriate to ask for such software in Stack Overflow?

Comment: No, you should post that on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/. Asking for tools, libraries, etc on SO is off-topic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

Try here - softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

But make sure to read their help pages https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic